# Проблема реализации exp из math.h

Tags: c, математика, численные-методы

У меня есть функция-копия exp из math.h. Она работает корректно, но на больших значениях (25<) начинает теряться точность по сравнению с оригиналом. Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли какая-нибудь формула или свойства чтобы работать в данном случае с большими значениями?

```
long double my_exp(double x) {
    if(x < 0){
        return 1.0/my_exp(-x);
    }
    long double sum = 1.0;
    long double term = 1.0;
    for(int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
        term *= x / i;
        sum += term;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Пример при my_exp(25), моя функция возвращает
72004899337.385918
а оригинальный exp(25)
72004899337.385880

my_exp(30)
10686474581524.459685
exp(30)
10686474581524.462891

Comment: стоит привести пример, где ты получаешь разные значения

Comment: Вы проверяли, как изменяется сумма на последних итерациях? Есть ли смысл останавливать счёт не по фиксированному количеству слагаемых, а по достижению неизменной суммы (предела точности)?

Comment: @Grundy Привёл пример

Comment: Вообще для сохранения точности рекомендуют складывать от меньших чисел к большим. Так что попробуйте пройти цикл в обратную сторону - от 99 до 1. Кстати, непонятно, почему именно до 99 цикл, это какая-то эмпирика?

Comment: Ещё стоит рассмотреть какие-нибудь преобразования что бы уменьшить икс. Ряд-то формально сходится всегда, но но на больших начальных значениях может сильнее накапливать ошибки округления.

Comment: Ваш пример для 25, а не 30

Comment: @CrazyElf Попробовал сделать, как вы сказали, стало вообще не сходиться. Насчёт 99 там без разницы, хоть 10000 погоды особой не сыграет.

Comment: @AlexeyTen Да, вот я и не знаю, как это реализовать

Comment: @CrazyElf 1/100! это уже ноль =)

Comment: Да, это я поторопился, там рекурсивное вычисление `term` и он там то растёт, то падает чуть не до нуля в конце, поэтому в обратную сторону не катит. А вообще видимо просто `double` недостаточно. Питон с типом `Decimal` или хотя бы `numpy.float64` по тому же алгоритму считает точнее.

Comment: 14-15 значащих цифр, это ок для double

Comment: Точность теряется при попытке сложить очень больше число с очень маленьким. Сохрани результаты умножения в массив, и сразу станет понятно чего нужно делать.

Comment: @AVI-crakHome кстати, интересная мысль, можно потом отсортировать массив и сложить от самых маленьких чисел до самых больших

Answer (score 3):

Как вариант. Причем широко используемый, по крайней мере, когда машины были большими :)

```
exp(a+b) == exp(a) * exp(b)

exp(n*x) == exp(x) ^ n
```

Так что считайте точно в каком-то приемлемом диапазоне, а затем приводите исходное значение `x` к этому диапазону. Например, вы умеете точно считать для `x` от 0 до 1, а надо для 30? Значит, возводите (быстрым возведением в степень) в 30-ю степень функцию от 1.

**Update**

Ладно, вот конкретный пример. Я взял аппроксимацию `exp(x)` именно из тех времен "больших машин"; вы напишите свою, более точную (учтите, что при возведении в степень N относительная точность упадет *примерно* в N раз...).
Привожу для простоты к диапазону 0-0.5.

```
//// Быстрое возведение в степень
double qpow(double x, unsigned int e)
{
    double res = 1.;
    for(;e;e>>=1)
    {
        if (e&1) res *= x;
        x *= x;
    }
    return res;
}

double apprexp(double x)  // exp(x), 0 << x << ln2 ~ 0.69
{
    return 1./(((((((-0.0001413161*x+0.0013298820)*x
           -0.0083013598)*x+0.0416573475)*x
           -0.1666653019)*x+0.4999999206)*x
           -0.9999999995)*x+1);
}

double qexp(double x)
{
    bool inv = x < 0;
    if (x < 0) x = -x;

    unsigned int ex = floor(x*2);
    x -= ex/2.;

    x = qpow(apprexp(0.5),ex)*apprexp(x);
    if (inv) x = 1/x;

    return x;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    for(double x = 0.001; x < 50; x *= 2)
    {
        cout << setprecision(10) << x << "\t\t" << exp(x) << "\t\t" << qexp(x) << endl;
    }
}
```

Вот, примерно так... Что сложного?

Comment: А можете подсказать, как конкретно в моём случае реализовать такой алгоритм?

Comment: Да я же все детально рассказал!

Comment: Просто я не могу использовать оригинальный pow, только свой, а мой использует мою exp, который косячит. Поэтому не до конца понимаю, как это реализовать.

Comment: @Bob умножать можно и без `pow` 

Comment: @AlexeyTen То есть, вот так как-то?

`if(x > 20){
        long double itog;
        itog = my_exp(1) * x;
        return itog;
    }`

Comment: @Bob, вот есть у вас большой *x*, вы хотите вычислить *y = e^x*, но *x* большой, считает не точно. Тогда вы считаете *a = x/2; b = e^a; y = bb;*. И получаете почти точный ответ, ошибка - пол ульпа.